# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, windows, sikuli

I'm getting a permission error when trying to save a screenshot from Sikuli under Windows.  The code that's doing the capturing is:

```
def CaptureScreenshot(self):
    resultsDirectory = os.path.join('C','08 May 2013 11 34','myname.png')
    screenshot = capture(self.screen)
    print(screenshot)
    shutil.move(screenshot,self.resultsDirectory)
```

When I print the screenshot path returned by `capture`, I get

```
D:\DOCUME~1\BUNNINGS\LOCALS~1\Temp\sikuli-scr-366782306192033926.png
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__pyclasspath__/Tests/Tests.py", line 12, in tearDown
  File "__pyclasspath__/Scripts/Screen.py", line 39, in CaptureScreenshot
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\shutil.py", line 205, in move
    copy2(src,dst)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\shutil.py", line 96, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\shutil.py", line 52, in copyfile
    fdst = open(dst, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C\\08 May 2013 11 34\\myname.png'
```

The destination folder exists and `myname.png` is the new name I am trying to give to the image.

I noticed that the destination folder's properties are set to "read only". Is this causing the issue? I couldn't change the readonly attribute; when I try, it just goes back to readonly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a colon missing after the `C` in your path. You are now trying to write in a subdirectory 'C' of the current directory.

Try to change the second line into:

```
resultsDirectory = os.path.join('C:','08 May 2013 11 34','myname.png')
                                  ^
```

Comment: @Loganswamy you can click the checkbox next to Anthon's answer to mark it as the correct solution.